# Correlation with target variable for regression problem

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-selection, correlation, pearsons-correlation-coefficient, spearmans-rank-correlation

Given the following dataframe

```
   age       job  salary
0    1    Doctor     100
1    2  Engineer     200
2    3    Lawyer     300    
...
```

with `age` as numeric, `job` as categorical, I want to test the correlation with salary, for the purpose of selecting the features (age and/or job) for predicting the salary (regression problem). Can I use the following API from sklearn (or other api)

```
sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression
sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_regression
```

to test it? If yes, what's the right method and syntax to test the correlation?

Following is the code of the dataset

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"age":[1,2,3],"job":["Doctor","Engineer","Lawyer"],"salary":[100,200,300]})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`mutual_info_regression`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_regression.html) for both continuous and discrete features. But first encode your `job` manually or using [`LabelEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html). Then get MI scores by specifying the index of `job` (here, $1$):

```py
X, y = df.drop(columns='salary'), df['salary']
X['job'] =  # encode this feature
mutual_info_regression(X, y, discrete_features=[1])
```